# Doubt regarding the completeness of ${\psi_n}$ in infinite potential well

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, boundary-conditions

The wavefunctions (without the time factor) for an infinite potential well (width: $0$ to $a$):
$$\psi_n=\sqrt{\frac{2}{a}}\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{a} \right).$$
The set of $\psi_n$ is complete as any other wavefunction can be written as:
$$ \Psi(x \text{,} 0) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_n \psi_n (x).$$
I was thinking this is just a Fourier series, but Fourier series contain both sine and cosine terms. Since $\psi_n$ are all sine here, how can we justify this completeness?

Comment: *any other wavefunction can be written as* Any other wavefunction that satisfies the boundary conditions of vanishing at $x=0$ and $x=a$.

Comment: @Ghoster The OP has some right here because [0,a] can be regarded as almost the whole axis. With choice of the frame '0' can be just as close to -inf and 'a' just close to +inf. Then we have almost any function which is zero at -+inf. And this is in fact any finction from practical point of view.

Comment: Are you reading Griffiths by any chance? He does say on page 34 [second edition. intro to quantum[ that ' "any" ' function can be expressed this way. And that it is only the "Fourier Series." He is very unclear here and I was confused by this myself. Griffiths is good but sometimes he's very informal to the point of being wrong or unintelligible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Completeness of energy eigenfunctions of the infinite potential well vs Fourier series](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/671139/)

Comment: @Ghoster That's not true. Any wavefunction can be expanded in terms of sines alone *regardless* of its behavior at the endpoints, because in this instance we refer not to pointwise convergence but rather convergence in the norm $\Vert \bullet \Vert$ as per my answer.

Comment: @J.Murray Thank you for the correction.

Comment: Related [MathSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1935801/are-sinn-pi-x-l-a-basis-of-l20-l) post.

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in reading about the [Fourier sine series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_sine_and_cosine_series).  The set of vectors
$$\psi_n(x) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{a}}\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{a}\right)$$

does indeed constitute an orthonormal basis for $L^2([0,a])$ in the sense that for each $\Phi\in L^2([0,a])$, there exists a sequence $\{c_n\}$ such that

$$\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \left\Vert \Phi - \sum_{n=1}^N c_n \psi_n\right\Vert = 0$$

This is what we mean by the existence of a complete orthonormal ([Schauder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_basis)) basis.

---

Note that this notion of convergence is not the same as **pointwise** convergence; since $\psi_n(0)=0$ for all $n$, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n \psi_n(0) = 0$. However, in quantum mechanics we don't care about the value of wavefunctions at individual points; this is a mathematical subtlety buried in the theory of $L^2$ spaces.  If two wavefunctions $\alpha$ and $\beta$ differ at a countable number of points (or more generally, in such a way that $\Vert \alpha-\beta \Vert = 0$), they are to be regarded as exactly the same vector. If you are interested, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Lp_spaces_and_Lebesgue_integrals) for more.

Comment: @Janik 1) $\cos(\pi(x+1/2))=-\sin(\pi x)\propto \psi_1$. 2) The Fourier sine series gives odd functions *when extended to the entire real line*. See [my related answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/671155/156895) for more about how an **arbitrary** function on $[0,a]$ can be extended to an odd function on $\mathbb R$. 3) The key is **almost everywhere**. The fact that it does not converge pointwise at $x=0$ and $x=a$ is irrelevant, because $\{0,a\}\subset[0,a]$ is a set of measure zero.

Comment: @Janik Besides all that, the operator $-\frac{1}{2}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$ with Dirichlet boundary conditions is self-adjoint on $L^2([0,a])$ and has purely discrete and nondegenerate spectrum, so its eigenfunctions must constitute a basis for $L^2([0,a])$ via the spectral theorem.